# Mathematica says integral diverges but I think it does not

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to compute Lebesgue measure of set $A=${$(x,y,z) :0<x,0<y, xy<z,x^4+z^4<x^2z$}

```
R = ImplicitRegion[x > 0 && y > 0 && x y < z && x^4 + z^4 < x^2 z, {x, y, z}]

Integrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] R]
```

Mathematica says that this integral is 0 but I think it is equal to $\frac{1}{8}$

Consider change of variables:

$$F(x,y,z)=(\frac{z}{x},y,z), y<x,z<\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}$$

Determinant of Jacobian is $\frac{z}{x^2}$

So integral becomes: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}}\frac{z}{x^2}dzdydx$ which is equal to $\frac{1}{8}$

Why is it happening?

$$$$

Comment: In the code for `R` you need a space between `xy` in `xy < z`.  But after fixing that `Reduce[x > 0 && y > 0 && x y < z && x^4 + y^4 < x^2 z, {x, y, z}]` results in `x > 0 && y > 0 && z > (x^4 + y^4)/x^2`.  That would make the code for the integral `Integrate[1, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y, 0, \[Infinity]}, {z, (x^4 + y^4)/x^2, \[Infinity]}]` which seems clearly infinity.  Am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: In the definition of `R` there is no constraint on `z`, it can be arbitrarily large. The volume is unbounded.

Comment: I edited my post, I made a silly mistake but something is still wrong, moreover after running this code second time mathematica don't output anything and is running all the time.

Comment: Your LaTeX equation has $x^4+y^4<x^2 z$ but the *Mathematica* code has `x^4 + z^4 < x^2 z`.  Did you forget to update the LaTeX equations?

Comment: yes, I forgot to update Latex equations

Answer (score 5):

Here's the region, which as @BobHanlon points out is unbounded in the $z$ direction, and hence indeed has infinite volume:

[image]

Comment: The "hence" isn't quite justified: one needs to observe that the cross-sections don't get too small. It suffices, for example, to note that $[\frac12,1]\times[0,1]\times[5,\infty)$ is a subset of $A$.

Comment: I edited my post, I made a silly mistake but something is still wrong, moreover after running this code second time mathematica don't output anything and is running all the time.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,the exact values is `1/8`,but `Integrate` or `RegionMeasure` seems unable to get this result. Here we use `NIntegrate`.

```
R = ImplicitRegion[
   x > 0 && y > 0 && x y < z && x^4 + z^4 < x^2 z, {x, y, z}]
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ R]
```

> `0.125`.

Answer (score 2):

If we limit $z<Z$, then we can calculate the volume exactly:

```
Assuming[Z > 0, 
  RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[
    x > 0 && y > 0 && x y < z && x^4 + y^4 < x^2 z && z < Z,
    {x, y, z}]]]

(*    π Z^2/(8 Sqrt[2])    *)
```

This clearly diverges as $Z\to\infty$.

Comment: I edited my post, I made a silly mistake but something is still wrong, moreover after running this code second time mathematica don't output anything and is running all the time.